# C# XElement without namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, linq-to-xml

I'm new to Xdocument and I need your help to understand what I'm doing wrong.

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    XNamespace ns = "http://somesite.com";
    XNamespace schemalocation = "http://somesite/schema.xsd";
    XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    XNamespace Xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    var date = DateTime.Now;
    var guid = "urn:uuid:" + Guid.NewGuid();


    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
     new XElement(ns + "Message",
                  new XAttribute("id", guid),
                  new XAttribute("messageType", Properties.Settings.Default.messageType),
                  new XAttribute("dateTime", date),
                  new XAttribute("origin", Properties.Settings.Default.origin),
                  new XAttribute("originType", Properties.Settings.Default.originType),
                  new XAttribute("destination", Properties.Settings.Default.destination),
                  new XAttribute("userName", Properties.Settings.Default.userName),
                  new XAttribute("xmlns", ns.NamespaceName),
                  new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", Xmlns),
                  new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", schemalocation),
                  new XElement ("Query",
                  new XElement("WhereClause", Properties.Settings.Default.WhereClause),
                  new XElement("ReturnStructure", Properties.Settings.Default.ReturnStructure)
                  )));
```

When I save the xml I'm getting an empty *xmlns* for child element "Query"

```
<Query xmlns="">
```

What changes do I need to do on my code to get "Query" without the namespace so it would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Message id="urn:uuid:4ed742cf-1ee4-4548-9105-c230933cf473" messageType="Type" dateTime="datetime" origin="service" originType="type" destination="destination" userName="username" xmlns="http://somesite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://somesite/schema.xsd">
      <Query>
        <WhereClause>somequery</WhereClause>
        <ReturnStructure>somereturn</ReturnStructure>
      </Query>
    </Message>
```

Thank for your help

Rafael

Comment: Just put that element in the right namespace (In your last bit of code, that namespace would be `http://somesite.com`, so add new `XAttribute("xmlns", ns.NamespaceName),` to your Query attribute. And then you probably want to do the same for its children...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the parent Namespace to Query tag and to the children of Query tag

```
new XElement (ns + "Query") 

new XElement (ns + "WhereClause")

new XElement (ns + "ReturnStructure")
```

Because once you add namespace to Query the child tags will be left without a namespace and they will show up with empty namespace tags.

Comment: Thanks Henk, I just saw the edit. I was wondering how to get the format correct. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Hi Lavin, also a big thank you for your quick answer and help. You rock!!

Comment: Glad to be able to help.